# cannot connect to the remote wsl on vs code (Error: [UriError]: cannot call joinPath on URI without path)

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

i'm trying to use wsl on vs code. it worked well until it unexpectedly stopped working.[image]

Any ideas on how can i fix this? I tried to uninstall and reinstall vs code as well as stopping the remote server but it did not work either. I'm still stuck on the workspace page without the possibility to do anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling doesn't affect the vscode server files in your home directory. Removing said files will cause a fresh install of said server and remote container files. So,

```
rm -r ~/.vscode*
code <wherever_you_like>
```